# Working with classes - resolve a NameError: global name

Tags: python, class, debugging, optimization

I am working with class object in order to improve my skills in programming. 
I have three files *.py. Sorry for the basic example but help me to understand where my error is:

```
/my_work_directory
   /core.py *# Contains the code to actually do calculations.*
   /main.py *# Starts the application*
   /Myclass.py *# Contains the code of class*
```

in `Myclass.py`

```
class Point(object):
    __slots__= ("x","y","z","data","_intensity",\
                "_return_number","_classification")
    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)
        self.z = float(z)
        self.data = [self.x,self.y,self.z]

   def point_below_threshold(self,threshold):
        """Check if the z value of a Point is below (True, False otherwise) a
            low Threshold"""
        return check_below_threshold(self.z,threshold)
```

in `core.py`

```
def check_below_threshold(value,threshold):
    below = False
    if value - threshold < 0:
        below = not below
    return below

def check_above_threshold(value,threshold):
    above = False
    if value - threshold > 0:
        above = not above
    return above
```

when I set main.py

```
import os
os.chdir("~~my_work_directory~~") # where `core.py` and `Myclass.py` are located

from core import *
from Myclass import *

mypoint = Point(1,2,3)
mypoint.point_below_threshold(5)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Myclass.py", line 75, in point_below_threshold
    return check_below_threshold(self.z,threshold)
NameError: global name 'check_below_threshold' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in other modules are not automatically visible in your `Myclass` module. You need to explicitly import them:

```
from core import check_below_threshold
```

or import the `core` module and use that as a namespace:

```
import core

# ...
    return core.check_below_threshold(self.z,threshold)
```

Comment: Thanks @Martijn, but if i have also other Functions, do i need import function-by-function?

Comment: I added a new function "def check_above_threshold". Do i need use from core import check_below_threshold, check_above_threshold?

Comment: @Gianni: yes; or import the whole module. `import core` then use `core.check_below_threshold(self.z,threshold)`, etc.

Comment: I miss some step. import core in Myclass.py?

Comment: @Gianni: You need to import functions you use in the correct modules, yes. If `Myclass.py` uses functions from `core`, then that's where you need to add `import core`, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing import.
You have to import your functions where you use them.
That means, you have to import check_below_threshhold in the core.py too, because it gets used there.